# Finding text within a string

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a string like so: `asdf text:a123a)! testing`. I would like to get this string and extract this string: `a123a)!`.

I'm trying to do it like so:

```
If TextBox.Text.Trim.ToUpper.Contains("TEXT:") Then
        Dim SearchStringFilter As String = TextBox.Text.Trim
        Dim FilterString As Match = Regex.Match(SearchStringFilter, "text:([A-Za-z0-9\-])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        If FilterString .Success Then
            Dim SubFilterString As String = StateFilterString.Value.ToUpper.Replace("TEST:", "")
            MessageBox.Show(SubFilterString)
        End If
    End If
```

However, this code does not seem to be working correctly. It will only output "1". Can anyone help?

Comment: You seem to know how to use `Contains`, why not use `Contains`? Regex is for pattern matching and you are looking for an exact string.

Comment: @JacobH Hey Jacob! Well, I thought about that, but I don't know how to get "a123a)!" using .contains.

Comment: @MatSnow Hello! No, I just want to extract "a123a)!" anything with a space after that should be omitted. So "asdf text:a123a)! testing" would become "a123a)!".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the part you need.

```
    Dim str As String = "asdf text:a123a)! testing"
    Dim index1 As Integer = str.IndexOf("text:") + "text:".Length
    Dim index2 As Integer = str.IndexOf(" ", index1)
    Dim result As String = str.Substring(index1, index2 - index1)
```

You'll need to add error checking.

If there's no space, you could get everything until the end.

```
    If index2 = -1 then
        result = str.Substring(index1)
    Else
        result = str.Substring(index1, index2 - index1)
    End If
```

Comment: Hey, it looks like index2 stays as -1 no matter what, resulting in an error for the fourth line.

Comment: @JasonMills if that is the case, then there are no space after "text:" and you should get the string until the end. str.Substring(index1)

Comment: I marked your reply as an answer, but just wondering, how would I do the same thing but if there isn't a space?

Comment: Works like an absolute charm. Thank you so much@

Answer (score 0):

You could use split :-

```
Dim Subject as string = "asdf text:a123a)! testing"
'
Dim DivArr As Char() = {":"c, " "c}
'split into segments using ":" and " " as separators - get 3rd element
Dim part3 As String = Subject.Split(DivArr)(2)
```

or one line

```
Dim part3 As String = Subject.Split({":"c, " "c})(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex.Split lets you split case-invariantly while keeping the original case of the text. Very handy.

```
Sub Ding()
    Dim firstItem As Boolean = True
    For Each s As String In Regex.Split(TextBox1.Text, "text:", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ' <-- this is the magic
        If firstItem Then
            firstItem = False 'the first item didn't have 'text:', so ignore it
        Else
            If s.Contains(" ") Then
                s = s.Split(" ").First
            End If
            MsgBox(s)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```